# How to change sidebar per page?

Tags: themes

I am new to theming with wordpress. I have a theme layout with one sidebar at the right side of the website.

Now on my homepage and one other page i dont want to have the sidebar. On all other pages it needs to stay. How can i do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... on my homepage **and one other page**
>   i dont want to have the sidebar.

You can tell WordPress to **do not generate** sidebar on specific page(s) with simple condition in your **page.php** file (or other relevant [template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List)).

For example the following piece of code will disable sidebar on 'About Me' page.

```
<?php if (!is_page('about-me')) get_sidebar(); ?>
```

*Note: you can use numeric ID or slug of your page inside the is_page() function.*

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register another sidebar.Look at twenty theme,in function.php file for example how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by removing the sidebar tag `<?php get_sidebar (); ?>` from the page templates you want.
If you use index.php as a homepage, you can duplicate it and name it homepage.php and remove the sidebar tag.

i suggest you to take a look at this pages:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Template_Tags